# Adding Done functionality to keyboard for UITextField

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitextfield

I have a view with two `UITextField`, one for username, one for password.

I added functionality so the `usernameTF` return button jumps to the `passwordTF`.  I also made the return button on the `passwordTF` "Go" which I want to connect to a `IBAction` I have which will contain the actual login logic.

I tried hooking up the `IBAction` to the passwordTF's `Did End On Exit` method but that just seemed to be getting called when the `usernameTF` was making the `passwordTF` the first responder.

I'm using this code to jump from `usernameTF` to `passwordTF`:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    if (textField == self.usernameTextField) {
        [self.passwordTextField becomeFirstResponder];
    }
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
```

I tried this but it does't call the method when I press Go/Return:

```
[self.passwordTextField addTarget:self
                               action:@selector(loginButtonPressed:)
                     forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingDidEndOnExit];
```

I also tried connecting the `IBAction` to the `UITextField`'s `Editing Did End` method which calls the method fine when I press the return button, but it also calls the method when I click any `UITextField` other than the one I have connected with that method.  Any fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using this

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    if (textField == txtfEmail)
        [txtfPassword becomeFirstResponder];
    else {
        [self login];
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Where `[self login]` is actually the login method being called. Validating login credential from Server or from Database. txtfEmail is Login Name and txtfPassword being the password field. Hope it helps

Comment: I connected the `IBAction` to the `UITextField`'s `Editing Did End` method which calls the method fine when I press the return button, but it also calls the method when I click any `UITextField` other than the one I have connected with that method.  Any fix?

Comment: The fix is as Rahul said.  If you only want the action to run when the user presses return, you need to hook it to the `textFieldShouldReturn:` method, not to the `UIControlEventEditingDidEndOnExit` event.  That's why they are separate.

Comment: OK, I did that by creating a separate `non-IBAction` login method and it worked fine.  But how can I use an `IBAction` and also a regular `void` method so I can hookup like Rahul said without having 2 of the same methods, with one being a `(void)` and the other being an `IBAction`?

Comment: Even if its an IBAction method you can still call it from your class, say -(IBAction)someMethod:(id)sender; being hooked with some event of a button, you can also make a call from some other function as [self someMethod:nil]; I am not sure if it's wrong but It does work.

Comment: This code only marginally works. See updated answer (A more flexible version...) with explanations of changes.

Comment: Yes, that's right. Return NO is required in the If section. Thanks for the update.

Answer (score 0):

@RahulSharma is almost there, but not quite.
It has **2 issues** addressed by the following approach:

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{
    // [textField resignFirstResponder];
    if (textField == txtfEmail) {
        [txtfPassword becomeFirstResponder];
        return NO; // Otherwise the "Return" char is posted onto next view
    } else {
        [self login];
    }
    return YES;
}
```

1. invoking `resignFirstResponder` is not necessary
2. returning `NO` will ensure that the CR will not be sent to the next control